# How to debug overridden code of a library function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, d3.js, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

This is my code snippet. As you can see the drawNodes function is overridden from the dagre-d3.js library for drawing directed graphs. However, when I assign a breakpoint at the line which starts with 'renderer.drawNodes', and 'step into', the control goes inside the library. If I step over, however, it skips this function and goes to the next line after the end of the function.

```
var oldDrawNodes = renderer.drawNodes();
renderer.drawNodes(function(graph, root) {
  var svgNodes = oldDrawNodes(graph, root);
  svgNodes.each(function(u) { d3.select(this).classed(graph.node(u).nodeclass, true); });
  return svgNodes;
});
```

My purpose is to debug the overridden code, I would like to watch the expression value of var svgNodes and more functionality which I plan to write there.

How do I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm off here but the code above doesn't appear to override anything.  You need to set oldDrawNodes to the function not an execution of it. var oldDrawNodes = renderer.drawNodes;  then to override drawNodes you need to assign. A function to it renderer.drawNodes = function(..... After that I suggest using the debugger; statement. Just add that to your function and the debugger will break when it hits that line.

Comment: @GordonBockus
view-source:http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/sentence-tokenization.html
Thanks Gordon, but can you please have a look at this link. It says that the function is being overridden.

Comment: This would be an override if it was `renderer.drawNodes = function() {}`, but that's not what is going on here.  This is not an override.  It's a function call you're passing a callback to.

Comment: @jfriend00 : Okayy, but how do I debug inside the callback then? I would like to go the section where var svgNodes is declared because I plan to add more code there. As I stated earlier, if I have a breakpoint at that line and step into, it takes me inside the dagre-d3 library code.

Comment: If you want to step through this code, then set a breakpoint on the `var svgNodes = oldDrawNodes(graph, root);` line.  Don't step into it because that will go to the oldDrawNodes function.  If you want to debug the `.each()` loop, then separate it into multiple lines so you can set breakpoints within it more easily.

Comment: @jfriend00 : Thanks for the reply, but I still don't get it. I have separated the code in .each() into it's own line(there is only one line of code inside .each, right)
I have breakpoints at lines  var svgNodes = oldDrawNodes(graph, root); and d3.select(this).classed(graph.node(u).nodeclass, true);
But still, at the line renderer.drawNodes(function(graph, root), if I step into, it takes me inside the dagre-d3.js file. If I step over, it skips this entire function and goes outside the scope.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you that I haven't already.  DON'T step into `renderer.drawNodes()`.  Set a breakpoint on the `var svgNodes` line and let it RUN until it hits that breakpoint (not stepping, but running).  There's nothing else I can tell you.  You might get better help if you explained the problem you're really trying to solve with this debugging.

Comment: @jfriend00 : like you said, the solution was to separate it into multiple lines so that breakpoints can be set more easily, and to let it RUN until it hits that breakpoint (not stepping, but running).
Thanks a lot.
But please can you add the above as an answer, so I can accept and upvote your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't step into `renderer.drawNodes()`. Make sure that your code is broken up into enough separate lines so you can set your breakpoint exactly where you want it.  Then set a breakpoint on the desired line line and let the debugger RUN until it hits that breakpoint (not stepping, but running).